# What are classes in memory?

Tags: assembly

I have been practicing assembly programming as a hobby for a few months now but my object-oriented mind keeps asking how classes are organized in RAM if they are at all.
Is there any formats that compilers use to store what a class is in ROM? How does it create an instance of said class into RAM? Then how does it know how to use the class such as data type lengths? - There's so many questions it's hard to ask as I have no clue.

I am not asking about memory management or data organization, I would like to know how a class is explained in assembly (as all things must be eventually), how instances are created and accessed.

I realise it is impractical to program objects in assembly however I would still like to know how a computer knows what 'objects' are.

Comment: What language? C++? Java? Even different compilers have different ways of structuring class.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Any compiler will be fine, I'm interested in the data structure that the asm will create in RAM and how it uses that.

Comment: For C/C++, a class is basically a `struct`. A `struct` is a concatenation of variables, possibly with padding. You can access a value in a struct by a pointer to the struct and the offset of the value in the struct.

Comment: @EOF This is the information that I keep being told and I know. I would like to know how a struct or class works, not how to use it in a language.

Comment: A C++ program has no idea what an object is. Only the compiler knows. Java has reflection so programs can find out lots of things about objects.

Comment: So in the assembly from a C++ program to read a 4 byte integer that is the third member of an object the compiler writes "move 4 bytes from object address plus 8 into register A" And to call a method it's "move object address into register F and call method address" It is all just addresses, sizes and offsets.  Objects don't exist.

Comment: @LeeAllan [this wiki on classes' claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) _"In type theory terms, a class is an implementation – a concrete data structure and collection of subroutines"_, how different classes' work depends on who created them, what their purpose is and the language they are implemented in.

Answer (score 2):

So, say you have a block of memory allocated for your struct (class). You have a pointer to it, let's call it `struct *x`. Now, you can write to it: `x->foo = 10`, or read from it `if (struct->bar) baz();`. 
To a real machine, this might look like:

```
mov 10, 4(%reg)  # where %reg holds the pointer to the struct's first member, 
                 # and .foo was 4 bytes (say, an int) into the struct

mov 8(%reg), %reg  # where %reg holds the pointer to x, 
                   # .bar is 8 bytes from the first member of the struct
test %reg, %reg
je otherstuff
call baz
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that all the struct's variable's lengths are known. Does the compiler usually hard-code the variable's offsets like that? I was really looking for how it creates and manages instances as surely that's the difference between a struct and a class - that the compiler knows the variables are local to the functions.

Comment: In C, the compiler *does* know all the variable's sizes (except gcc has a non-standard C extension that supports VLAIS [variable-length arrays in structs], but only as the *last* member of a struct), so yes, it is *that* static. You can have structs within structs, so inheritance (of a kind) is possible, so C structs and C++ classes are pretty much equivalent (AFAIK, you can declare a class in C++ by writing `struct`).

Comment: @LeeAllan: As for allocation and initialisation: Well, in C, you're doing pretty much what I wrote: allocate memory (stack or heap), then initialise the members of the struct. In C++, you've got constructors... Which do the same thing, under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (with considerable liberties taken) --

First understand that there's a difference between an "object" and a "class".  Let's discuss an "object" (eg, the String object) first:

**The object** consists of bytes allocated in "garbage collected heap".  Typically the object allocation will start on an 16-byte boundary (though some JVMs may use 8, some 32).  There may be 16-32 bits of some sort of identifier, used to identify a valid object and help out during GC scanning, or maybe not.  After that (or first, if no identifier) is usually a pointer to the object's class structure.  (This is a pointer to a C `struct` or C++ object, not a Java object.)  There will likely be an additional 8 bytes or so of data used to handle GC, perform object locking, and maybe a few other tasks.

After that is the actual object data.  In a String this consists of a pointer to the `char` array for the String, and the String's length.  In older versions there was also an offset value, since a String that was substring of another String might "share" it's `char` array.  But newer versions don't do it this way.

Somewhere, either in the header or in the object data, will be a field to contain the object's hash value.  This is usually left zero initially and calculated on first reference to the hash value.

An array object will have "object data" that effectively consists of the array length followed by the actual array bytes.  (Though in some cases the array length field uses available space in the object header.)

**The class** `struct` (or C++ object) contains a large amount of info about the class.  The most important parts are:

- The "constant pool" that contains string literals, the names and attributes of fields and methods, the names of external fields and methods to be linked to, and other constants used by the program.
- The "virtual method table" (probably called several different names in different JVMs).  This table contains pointers to all the methods that one can invoke on the class, including those in superclasses.  The methods of Object would be first in the class, so that in every class in the system the method `toString()` would be, say, entry # 7.  Then, say, if this is the class for `Double`, the methods of `Number` (the superclass of `Double`) would appear in the table, followed by the methods of `Double` itself.  This way, if you have a pointer declared as `Number`, the JVM will always know to invoke, say, entry # 19 to invoke `shortValue()`, regardless of the actual type of the object.
- The pointer to the class's instance of `Class` (which is just an object like an instance of String is an object).  The `Class` instance contains only a handful of values, most notably a `long` value which is, in reality, the pointer back to the C/C++ class structure.
- And of course other data -- debug info, pointers to the various secondary tables, etc.